# Extract numbers separated by special char from string

Tags: php

If I have a string like:

```
123*23*6594*2*-10*12
```

How can I extract the single numbers, in the string separated by `*`? That is, I want this output:

```
a=123, b=23, c=6594, d=2, e=-10, f=12.
```

Comment: use `explode("*",$str)` will give you an array of data.

Comment: explode("*", $str); return an array

Comment: Is it always going to be `*` or `/`, `+`, `-`, ... I mean... What's the final point of this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flexible:

```
$vars = range('a', 'z');
$vals = explode('*', $string);
$result = array_combine(array_slice($vars, 0, count($vals)), $vals);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [a] => 123
    [b] => 23
    [c] => 6594
    [d] => 2
    [e] => -10
    [f] => 12
)
```

Comment: `$vals = explode('*', $string);` is more flexible by its own

Comment: Unless you want string letters as the key as in the OP.

Comment: Which is obviously a bad idea... But yeah it is still better

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
list($a,$b,$c,$d,$e,$f) = explode("*", $str);
```

Just a guess ;)

Comment: And i guess it's just inflexible!

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple as this :

```
$str = "123*23*6594*2*-10*12";
$arr = explode("*",$str);
$arr['a']=$arr[0];
$arr['b']=$arr[1];
$arr['c']=$arr[2];
$arr['d']=$arr[3];
$arr['e']=$arr[4];
$arr['f']=$arr[5];

echo "a=" .$arr['a'] ." b=". $arr['b']." c=". $arr['c']." d=". $arr['d']." e=". $arr['e']." f=". $arr['f'];
```

**EDIT:**

To accomplish Rizier123 wish :

```
$str = "123*23*6594*2*-10*12";
$arr = explode("*",$str);
$vars = range('a', 'z');

foreach ($arr as $val => $key){
    echo $vars[$val]."=".$key."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Huff, i hope that this string never changes! Otherwise your answer doesn't help anymore!

Comment: @Rizier123 yes is just an example for the string provided.

Comment: @Rizier123 and why do you say that ?

Comment: Why i feel some people are here only to criticize answers, if the know why just not simply post an answer and stop bugging the others... just my two cents...

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sheer fun of setting the result as an iterable (rather than an actual array) with the alpha keys in a slightly different manner:

```
$data = '123*23*6594*2*-10*12';

function dataseries($data) {
    $key = 'a';
    while (($x = strpos($data, '*')) !== false) {
        yield $key++ => substr($data, 0, $x);
        $data = substr($data, ++$x);
    }
    yield $key++ => $data;
}


foreach(dataseries($data) as $key => $value) {
    echo $key, ' = ', $value, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Requires PHP >= 5.5.0